# Parameter "isMoving" does not exist

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I was following tutorial video but somehow end up error like this
[image]

This is the code
[image]

Any clue where is the problem, I tried changing things but still no different...

Comment: Please always add code in text form instead of as an image. That makes it much easier for people to help you, because they can just copy your code, try it out themselves, and then give you a corrected version which you can then also copy.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for this warning would be that the AnimatorController you show in your screenshot is not actually the AnimatorController that is attached to the Animator referenced in your code. Did you assign the AnimatorController asset you are editing to the field "Controller" in the inspector of the Animator of the object this script is on?